# Google Nearby API rank_by not ordering results

Tags: google-api

I'm using the the Google Nearby Search API where I can put in a location (in latitude and longitude) and filter on type and key word.  But when I add the rank_by parameter with it ranking by distance it doesn't seem to be working as it should bring back the nearest store.  For example (please note that I have deliberately excluded the api key in all the codes below) I first get my latitude and longitude by providing a postcode (W1A 1EX) using the Geocode API:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=W1A 1EX&components=country:GB
```

That returns

```
"lat": 51.5245669,
"lng": -0.1120165
```

I then plug them into the nearbysearch API

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?keyword=white%20stuff&location=51.5245669%2C-0.1120165&radius=5000&type=clothing_store&rank_by=distance
```

which returns me place_id

```
ChIJVVUVyNQadkgRXL1uIjhpNmU
ChIJSyGhZ2cbdkgRcpN0-WodNzU
```

in that order.

If I then use the Place Details API to convert the above place_ids, I get

```
W1C 1DX
N1 8LN
```

Now going back to Google Maps, the distance between W1A 1EX and W1C 1DX is 1.8 miles walking and 3.8 miles driving, but the distance between W1A 1EX and N1 8LN is only 1 mile for both walking and driving.  So why is

```
rank_by=distance
```

not working in the nearbysearch API?

Furthermore, I've noticed that if I change the nearby API to using a smaller radius (say 2000m), it does return me the closest store.  But I thought the whole point of increasing the radius but ranking by distance is so I can find the nearest store?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?keyword=white%20stuff&location=51.5245669%2C-0.1120165&radius=2000&type=clothing_store&rank_by=distance
```